# Database table to handle OR conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I currently have a system which based on certain answers provided by a user certain sections are shown.  currently I had it designed as:

Id---SectionId---QuestionId---Answer

for example, if User answered Y to question 12 I would enable Section 21.  If they answered Y to both 13 AND 14 then Section 22 would be enabled.

```
1 --- 21 --- 12 --- Y
2 --- 22 --- 13 --- Y
2 --- 22 --- 14 --- Y
```

This was working fine, recently I started receiving request which are based on an OR condition. I was thinking of changing the table to the below design, but wanted feedback, if there is a better way to approach this:

```
Id---SectionId---ConditionalId
1---21---12
2---21---13

ConditionalId---QuestionId---Answer
12---4---Y
12---5---N
13---6---Y
13---7---Y
```

So this way for Section 21 to display the system would have to verify either ConditiondalId 12 or 13, if either is valid then display.

Comment: Then how are you going to handle `AND` conditions in the future?

Comment: @RBarryYoung for AND the second table should verify both conditions, so for example above is we have 1-21-12 that means in order for 21 to show all conditions for 12 must be meet, so both Questions 4&5 have to be met. conditionalId can be a block of answers which all have to be met, so this should work for AND as well.

Comment: Yes, I know how `AND` works, I was asking how you were going to handle such conditions in you DB tables/schema?

Answer (score 0):

You should not save ConditionalId with the answer of the user.

UserAnswers table:
    UserID - QuestionId - Answer

Question Table:
    QuestionId - NextLevelId - ChildLevelCondition (0 for any, 1 for all)

Each question Id can tell from ChildLevelCondition how it should check the level below for Y and N. 
If at the child you don't have as many Y as question and ChildLevelCondition = 1, it is not allowed. With at least 1 Y and ChildLevelCondition = 0, you can go to this level
You can use a group by and a case